# Duplicate component designators error in verilog

Tags: verilog

I am getting an error "Affected Objects  Duplicate Component Designators i4 at Line:25 Offset:13 and Line:25 Offset:13". Since both the location specified are same I could not sort this issue. Kindly help me.

This is the code I am using.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module delay_output(
  input cclk3,
  input [7:0] delay_out1,
  output reg[7:0] delayout1
);

reg [7:0] temp1;
reg [7:0] temp2;
reg [7:0] temp3;
reg [7:0] temp4;

delay_outsig(
  .cclk4(cclk4),
  .delay_out2(delayout1)
);

always @(posedge cclk3) begin
  temp1 <= delay_out1;
  temp2 <= temp1;
  temp3 <= temp2;
  temp4 <= temp3;
  delayout1<= temp4;
end

endmodule
```

Comment: `delayout1` seems t be assigned from two places: `delay_outsig` and the always the always block. This is illegal, there should only be one driver. Where is `cclk4` defined?

Answer (score 0):

As I don't know which tools you are using, I am just guessing.

One problem I identified is the use of the `delayout1` designator:

- In the `module` declaration this was specified as type `output reg [7:0]`.
- On line 25 however, it connects to an instance port, which requires a `wire` instead of a `reg`.

Therefore I would simply remove `reg` from the `output` declaration so it becomes

```
output [7:0] delayout1
```

and see if that resolves the error. Let me know if it helped.

#### EDIT

In addition to the above, I realised that you are also assigning to `delayout1` inside the `always` block which requires `delayout1` to be a `reg`.

So there is the problem that `delayout1` cannot be a `reg` *and* at the same time *not* be a `reg`. Assuming that the `delay_out2` port of the `delay_outsig` instance is an output, there is a conflict between the `always` block and the `delay_outsig` instance - which of the two should be driving `delayout1`?

In addition to that, the instantiation of the `delay_outsig` module is missing an instance name and `cclk4` is not defined (thanks [Greg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32732277/duplicate-component-designators-error-in-verilog/32733704?noredirect=1#comment53334408_32732277) for noting this).

So in short, the code has the following issues:

1. The `delay_outsig` instance needs a name. You could for example change the line to `delay_outsig delay_outsig_inst1 (` to give the instance the name `delay_outsig_inst1`.
2. There is a driver conflict between the `delay_outsig` instance and the `always` block. You need to decide which one of the two should be controlling `delayout1`. Perhaps you need to use a separate name for the other driver and combine the two somehow.
3. Once you decided that, `delayout1` should be a wire if it is driven by an instance or a `reg` if it is driven by an `always` block.
4. You should define `cclk4` (is this maybe a typo and should be `cclk3`?)

Looking at your code at a higher level (i.e. guessing what you are really trying to do), I am wondering if you need to have the `delay_outsig` instance at all or if you want to maybe remove those four lines and see if the module already does what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply.  I tried the option u have suggested. But inside always i couldnot assign delayout1 if it is not a register.  Also i have used the same call for other module. it is working fine. but this one is not working. I using altium 3AN kit.

Comment: @Arthi, please see my updated answer. Note that I assumed that `delay_out2` is an output of `delay_outsig`, let me know if that (or anything else) is not what it should be.

Comment: delay_out2 is an input of delay_outsig. also i have tried giving an instance for delay_outsig. Still the problem is there. cclk4 is a clock input.

Comment: @Arthi, if both `cclk4` and `delay_out2` are *inputs* to the `delay_outsig` instance, what does this instance do? You could safely remove it, since it doesn't contribute to anything within your circuit. I also suggest you to edit your question to clarify what you are really trying to achieve. Otherwise we'll have to keep guessing which isn't really helpful to anyone.